# jquery css selector to match elements with id contains specific text after the last dot

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to write css selector for jquery that matches elements with id that contains some text after the last dot.
Something that resembles  `$(div[id*='cow'])` - but stronger because I need it to match only if the text is after last dot.
So take everything after the last dot and see if the text contains my string.
For example text to look for - **cow**

```
<div id ='my.very.first.cow'></div> // get it
<div id = 'my.very.first.cowandcat'></div> //get it
<div id = 'my.very.firstcow.andcat'></div> //DON'T get it - not after the last dot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend the selectors using:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{......
```

The snippet:

```js
;(function($){
    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        IdTextAfterLastDot: function(a, b, c) {
            var id = a.id;  // get current ID
            var sel = c.pop();  // get the parameter
            var idx = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).indexOf(sel);
            //
            // If after last dot the id text starts with ....
            //
            return idx == 0;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);


//
// Use the new selector
// 

$('div:IdTextAfterLastDot(cow)').each(function(idx, ele) {
    console.log('selected: ' + ele.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id ='my.very.first.cow'></div>
<div id = 'my.very.first.cowandcat'></div>
<div id = 'my.very.firstcow.andcat'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To match anything that ends with `.cow`

```
div[id$='.cow'] {background-color: blue}
```

Comment: No I don't know the whole text after the dot. I am just trying to find my string in that text portion. catandcow , cowandcat, dogandcowandcat, cow - they are all a match as long as they are coming after the last dot.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood. It needs to be written with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

im not shure if i understand your problem but try this if helps.

```js
$("div").each(function(){ 
 var item = $(this);
  var arr = item.attr("id").split('.');  
  console.log(arr)
  n = arr[arr.length-1].indexOf("cow");
  if(n!=-1)
  {
   alert(item.attr("id"));      
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ='my.very.first.cow'></div> // get it
<div id = 'my.very.first.cowandcat'></div> //get it
<div id = 'my.very.firstcow.andcat'></div> //DON'T get it - not after the last dot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var ids = $('div');
$.each(ids,function(index,value){
  var ids_split = this.id.split('.'), id_length = ids_split.length, last_class=ids_split[id_length-1], search_term = "cow";
if (last_class.includes(search_term)) {

    $(this).addClass('cows_only');  
  
     // only .cow is selected 
} 

});
```

```html
<div id ='my.very.first.cow'></div> // get it
<div id = 'my.very.first.cowandcat'></div> //get it
<div id = 'my.very.firstcow.andcat'></div> //DON'T get it - not after the last dot
```

This iterates your divs and grabs the id whose last . has "cow" somewhere. Here is a fiddle:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g4s5zcm/1/)

Notice how classes are only added to the divs with "cows" after the last dot.